# how to add a subheading as a second-level header tag?

Tags: html, css

How do you add a subheading "A New York Eatery" in a second-level header tag under h1?

example:

## esha's restaurant

Comment: can you please explain your requirement more clearly?

Comment: the title is esha's restaurant as <h1> in HTML part but im instructed to add a subheading  "A New York Eatery" in a second level header tag under h1 i was thinking that means tagging it as <h2>  but im not sure where to do that or if i should code that under the css style under <h1>

Comment: can you please share images related to your requirement if any?

Comment: I figured it out the answer to add subheading into a second level tag its "A New York Eatery"<h2></h2>  after the title Esha Restraunt<h1></H1> under it in html body.

Comment: </head>
<body>
<h1>esha's restaurant</h1> 
<h2>A New York City Eatery</h2>

Comment: thanks for effort in helping me i truly appreciate it@nagendranag nag

Comment: Thank you. if you find the answer to it you can post the answer in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1>esha's restaurant</h1>
<h2>A New York Eatery</h2>
```